# Testing oAuth login flow

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, shopify

I'm creating a shopify app. I've written express middleware that will take a shop via query parameter so the route with "/?shop=example-shop" will kick off the login flow, from there the user gets redirected to shopify where if they aren't already logged in they do so then "install" the app, approving my apps keys. Then they get sent back to the app where I exchange the code for an access token and do other things like store the user. There's a lot that happens when they come back to the server and I'm having trouble deciding how to test everything. For one I can't even test this route unless all of the returned params are valid (signature, hmac, timestamp).

I'm thinking I could use Casper to login to shopify and follow the flow.

How can I test this very complicated login flow, with valid get parameters?

All the local stuff is easy to test, like database calls. However I can't fake / mock keys and the access token exchange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the OAuth 2 login flow works something like this:

[image]

1. You make a request to your route.
2. It sends back a `3xx` that redirects you to (in your case) Shopify.
3. On the Shopify portal, you fill in the form and log in (sending a POST to them). This ends the "Authenticating the user" part.
4. A `3xx` is sent back that redirects you to a different route.
5. When the second route is hit, it sends a request to Shopify to authenticate the server. Upon successful authentication of the server (now the user and server are authenticated), it's safe for Shopify to return the data, which your second route will receive.

---

## Unit Testing

Think about how your routes would be unit tested.

- Your first route receives a GET request, and sends back a `3xx` without doing anything else.
- Your second route receives a GET request, receives some sort of user object from Shopify, might do something with the user object, and then sends back a `3xx`.

So for the first route, you'd really only be testing that the GET request sends back a `3xx`. For the second, you might want to test anything the server does with the user object it gets back.

But as you mention, Shopify will only send back the user object if the user and server have been authenticated, and you won't be doing this full fledged authentication with your Unit test. What you'd want to do is mock the response from Shopify! Ie. when the request is made to the second route and you're in a testing environment, instead of authenticating with Shopify, just mock the user object you'd get back and continue to do whatever you'd normally do with that object. If you want to do a true *unit* test, this is the way to go.

---

## Integration Testing

Alternatively, you might want to do a full [integration test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing) of this entire process. There's a lot of ways to do this, but basically you'd go through the 1-5 steps I outlined above. You'd probably want to set up a account with Shopify that is used for this test.

Comment: I like the idea of mocking the response from Shopify, however how can I mock the `code` and converting it to an actual `access_token`? The only thing I can think of is using a headless browser and generating the query to the second route then passing it into the unit test.

Comment: Can't you just make up values for everything? In my graph, what would be mocked would be `{ token, refreshToken, profile }`. You'd mock whatever the analogous data is from Spotify. Basically, at some point you'll have your data from Spotify and you'll then be (potentially) doing some stuff with it before sending some response to the client. You'll want to mock right up until the point where you start using the data yourself. Sorry if that wasn't clear, it'd be a lot easier to point to and explain visually. It's also possible that I'm not fully understanding your situation.

Comment: Within the second route I get data from shopify including `code`, `hmac`, `signature`, and `timestamp`. These are generated by Shopify. There is a method of validating these ([here some code](https://gist.github.com/reggi/5fde5b09db506a9f5f1c)) I love the idea of faking all the data, but this is unfakeable no? How can I generate a fake set of data that passes this piece of the middleware?

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. What I would do is I would bypass the middleware with this unit test, and have separate tests for the middleware itself. So for this middleware, write code that says "if we're in the testing environment, skip the middleware". Then, as a separate unit test, check that the middleware functions return the right output for a various given inputs. Otherwise, you'd be testing 1) the middleware and 2) your other code in the same unit test. If the unit test failed, how do you know whether it was because (1) or (2)?

Comment: I think you meant `Shopify` in your Integration Testing section